# Pipe aws output to jq will not result in array

Tags: arrays, shell, jq, aws-cli

I try to use to get all hosts from an elbv2 LoadBalancer rule to an array to expand the list.
I tried to query the existing hosts inside the rule with

```
TESTOUTPUT=$(aws elbv2 describe-rules --rule-arns arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:xxxx:listener-rule/app/k8s-ctrlroute-xxx/xxx/xxx --region ap-northeast-1 --no-cli-pager)
```

works great, I get the JSON with the hosts back. No I try to parse the output direct to an Array with

```
TESTOUTPUT=$(aws elbv2 describe-rules --rule-arns arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:xxxx:listener-rule/app/k8s-ctrlroute-xxx/xxx/xxx --region ap-northeast-1 --no-cli-pager | jq [.Rules[0].Conditions[0].Values[]])
```

The result are the expected hosts. It looks like

```
[ "host1.cloud", "host2.cloud", "host3.cloud" ]
```

But if I not try to add an entry with TESTOUTPUT+="host4.cloud" I will get

```
[ "host1.cloud", "host2.cloud", "host3.cloud" ]host4.cloud
```

So I assume the expected array is not an array. But the jq output is the syntax for array output.
Maybe someone can borrow me two eyes for a different view on the case to find out what is wrong in my code.

Comment: You seem to be confusing JSON arrays and Bash arrays. From Bash's perspective, any JSON output is just a (JSON-encoded) string, thus `+=` just appends to that string.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's still just a string, albeit a string which would represent a valid JSON array if you gave it to a JSON parser; but Bash is not one.

If you want to get the output in a Bash array, try

```
testoutput=($(aws elbv2 describe-rules \
    --rule-arns arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:xxxx:listener-rule/app/k8s-ctrlroute-xxx/xxx/xxx \
    --region ap-northeast-1 --no-cli-pager |
  jq '[.Rules[0].Conditions[0].Values[]] | @sh'))
```

The crucial changes are

- parentheses around the value to actually assign to an array, not a string scalar
- adding the `| @sh` decorator to the `jq` expression

Also, for good measure, single-quote the `jq` expression; and add backslash line wraps to untangle the horrendously long command line.

The next inevitable question if you are unfamiliar with Bash arrays is, "how do I examine the array?"

```
printf '%s\n' "${testoutput[@]}"
```

to print all of it, or

```
for value in "${testoutput[@]}"; do
    : something with "$value"
done
```

to loop over them individually.

Beginners tend to try

```
echo "$testoutput"
```

(even without the quotes, for a true beginner)
and be flabbergasted when it only prints the first element.

Tangentially also [don't use upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: I obviously don't have access to your AWS environment so I have assumed that the output is what you say it is. There are probably also ways to format the `aws` CLI output into a Bash array directly. Maybe look at the `--query` and `--output` options.

Answer (score 0):

`jq` speaks json, but most programs do not.  If you want to manipulate json, you'll want to do it with `jq`.

```
 echo '{"Rules": [ { "Conditions":[ { "Values": [ "host1.cloud", "host2.cloud", "host3.cloud" ] } ] } ] }' \
|jq '.Rules[0].Conditions[0].Values += ["host4.cloud"]'
{
  "Rules": [
    {
      "Conditions": [
        {
          "Values": [
            "host1.cloud",
            "host2.cloud",
            "host3.cloud",
            "host4.cloud"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```